# Повторное отрисовка надписей при использовании multiplot в gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Имеется проблема. Я хочу нарисовать несколько графиков в одном окне с помощью gnuplot. Я устанавливаю все нужные мне надписи (tics, title, label и т.д.). Далее я включаю режим multiplot и рисую несколько графиков, но у меня накладываются все надписи. Как нарисовать несколько графиков в одном окне с одними общими надписями? Окно для рисования общее, то есть я никуда не сдвигаю окно для отрисовки следующего графика.

Например,

```
set xlabel('t, m/s')
set multiplot
plot sin(x)
plot sin(2*x)
unset multiplot
```

Здесь надпись "t, m/s" отобразится дважды.

Или, предположим, я хочу нарисовать два графика. Как сделать, чтобы легенда графика не накладывалась на одном месте, а располагалась одна под другой в случая двух графиков?

Comment: А зачем Вы хотите использовать `multiplot`? Как я понял, Вам нужно просто поместить два графика в одних осях координат? Так и рисуйте их одной командой plot: `plot sin(x), sin(2*x)`. А `multiplot` нужен, чтобы разместить на одном рисунке несколько осей координат рядом (или сверху/снизу).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, действительно работает.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что диапазон изменения осей в этих файлах одинаков? В случае с sin(x) - там и область определения, и область значений - совпадают. В общем, мне кажется, что нужно просто глянуть на Ваши данные из этих файлов...

Comment: Извините, я запятую не ставил между путями с данными.